# Display 3 images from url to cell of Collection View Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, alamofire

i requested 3 image url from an API. and i want to display 3 images from url images that have been obtained to cell on Collection View. i'm new to swift programming

here's my code

```
class MainCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Alamofire.request(.POST, "URL").responseJSON { response in

        if let value = response.result.value {

            let json = JSON(value)

            let data = json["data"].arrayValue

            for datas in data {

                let result = datas["image"].stringValue

                print(result)

            }
        }
    }
}

override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MainCollectionViewCell

        return cell
     }
}
```

my Image View is on mainCollectionViewCell named mainImageView

Comment: Here result will print image URL right?

Comment: yup, it wil print image url

Comment: you should google any general tutorial for web request. most of them do similar stuff that you want

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a forum. Do not add "solved" to your question. Either select and approve an existing answer, or post an answer yourself. That's the way of saying "solved" on this site. Read the FAQ. Thanks.

Comment: oh, ok thanks for the information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved It. here's my code

```
class MainCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {


@IBOutlet var mainCollectionView: UICollectionView!
var url = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Alamofire.request(.POST, "URL").responseJSON { response in

        if let value = response.result.value {

            let json = JSON(value)

            let data = json["data"].arrayValue

            for datas in data {

                self.url.append(datas["image"].stringValue)
            }
            self.mainCollectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return url.count
}

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MainCollectionViewCell



                let imageUrl:NSURL? = NSURL(string: url[indexPath.row])

                if let url = imageUrl {

                    cell.mainImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(url)

        }
        return cell
}
```

i'm using SDWebImages to display the image

Comment: What if I have 2000 or more images?

Answer (score 0):

Write something like below in your code,

```
class MainCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

var myImageArray : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

Alamofire.request(.POST, "URL").responseJSON { response in

    if let value = response.result.value {

        let json = JSON(value)

        let data = json["data"].arrayValue

        for datas in data {

            let result = datas["image"].stringValue

            self.myImageArray.addObject(result)
            print(result)

        }
    }
}
}

override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
return 1
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return self.myImageArray.count
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MainCollectionViewCell

    let url = NSURL(string: self.myImageArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as String)
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!) //make sure your image in this url does exist, otherwise unwrap in a if let check
    cell.mainImageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)

    return cell
 }
}
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: You can also use third party library like SDWebImage to load image from URL.

Comment: it say 'AnyObject' is not convertible to 'String'; did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast? on line `let url = NSURL`

then i add '!' after as. then the build succeded but it print SIGABRT error

Comment: Is your mainImageView is wire-up or connected with ImageView in your cell? and check via putting some breakpoint at url, data and image view. And also print Url in cell to check whether array is having it or not?

Comment: my mainImageView is already connected to UIImageView in my CollectionViewCell.swift. And then i putting some breakpoint to url, data, and image view in collectionViewCell.swift. It display green line on my imageView on collectionViewCell.swift says Thread 1: breakpoint 1.4, and Thread 1: breakpoint 1.2 and in my `let url = NSURL` says Thread 1: breakpoint 2.1. i try to print url and get SIGABRT error too. Sorry, but i'm also new to programming too

Comment: Have you run your app without giving image? is it running without giving image?

Comment: did you mean the Image View?

Comment: Yes just comment that three lines of code inside the cellForItem method and then check it. Just tell me that is it working fine before you add this code?

Comment: it's Working fine, and show url of 3 images

Comment: Ok, Good. then try by changing those code, Replace it like,

if let url = NSURL(string: "http://etc...") {
    if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
        imageURL.image = UIImage(data: data)
    }        
}

Comment: on "etc..." must be filled by what? if the result, it cant because unresolved identifier.

Comment: it filled by : self.myImageArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as String   - Pass url as given in my answer

Comment: oh, i solved it. just add global variable at top, and append that variable with my images url, after for in add reloadData() and then use SDWebImages to display the image on cellForItemAtIndexpath

Comment: and on numberOfItemsInSection `return "the global variable" .count`

Comment: I edited my answer so please check it.

Comment: i'm using `let imageUrl:NSURL? = NSURL(string: url[indexPath.row]) if let url = imageUrl { cell.mainImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(url) }` on my `cellForItemAtIndexpath`

and for my global variable, i use `var url = [String]()` and for append data i use `self.url.append(datas["image"].stringValue)` on For In. then outside for in, i add some code `self.mainCollectionView.reloadData()` to reload data

Comment: Replace it like -> if let imageUrl:NSURL? = NSURL(string: url[indexPath.row])
        {
            cell.mainImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(imageUrl)
        }
        self.mainCollectionView.reloadData()